# Custom Profile Center Throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, profile-center

I've set up a custom profile center, based on a boiler plate from adam spriggs and its working on the preview, but it breaks when I try to open it from an email or open it from a email preview.

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

    // src: https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8
    // demo: https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/yo3hzpktgmu?qs=7145718410d87e2af4e5001112e1de43e2e457b69041ac21&mid=7203368

    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    var debug = true;
    var request = {};

    SetVar("method", Request.Method)
    SetVar("urlThis", Platform.Request.RequestURL);
    SetVar("MasterDEKey", "ExampleMaster");
    SetVar("debug", debug);

    if (request.method == "GET") {

        if (debug) {
            Write("GET<br>");
        }

        // retrieve the subscriberkey via system personalization string from the send context
        SetVar("SubscriberKey", Attribute.GetValue("_SubscriberKey"));

        if (request.SubscriberKey != "") {

          // retrieve the row from the Master DE
          var masterRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows(request.MasterDEKey,['SubscriberKey'], [request.SubscriberKey]);

          if (debug) {
            Write("<br>masterRows.length: " + masterRows.length);
            Write("<br>masterRows: " + Stringify(masterRows));
          }

          // set variables for the Master column values (for defaulting below)
          if (typeof masterRows !== 'undefined' &&  masterRows.length > 0) {

            // DE field names are case-sensitive
            SetVar("SubscriberKey", masterRows[0]["SubscriberKey"]);
            SetVar("EmailAddress", masterRows[0]["EmailAddress"]);
            SetVar("FirstName", masterRows[0]["FirstName"]);
            SetVar("LastName", masterRows[0]["LastName"]);
            SetVar("JobTitle", masterRows[0]["JobTitle"]);
            SetVar("Industry", masterRows[0]["Industry"]);
            SetVar("Company", masterRows[0]["Company"]);

          }

        }

    } else if (request.method == "POST") {

        if (debug) {
            Write("POST<br>");
        }

        // get form field values
        SetVar("SubscriberKey", Request.GetFormField("SubscriberKey"));

        // if the SubscriberKey is blank then fall back and use the email address
        if (request.SubscriberKey == "") {
            SetVar("SubscriberKey", Request.GetFormField("EmailAddress"));
        }

        // retrieve values from the form submission
        // form field names are case-sensitive
        SetVar("EmailAddress", Request.GetFormField("EmailAddress"));
        SetVar("FirstName", Request.GetFormField("FirstName"));
        SetVar("LastName", Request.GetFormField("LastName"));
        SetVar("JobTitle", Request.GetFormField("JobTitle"));
              SetVar("Industry", Request.GetFormField("Industry"));
              SetVar("Company", Request.GetFormField("Company"));

        if (request.SubscriberKey != "") {

          try {

              // set values for Subscriber update
              var sub = {
                     "SubscriberKey": request.SubscriberKey
                   , "EmailAddress": request.EmailAddress
                   , "Status" : "Active"
              };

              // initialize the Subscriber object
              var subObj = Subscriber.Init(request.SubscriberKey);

              // add/update the Subscriber
              SetVar("subscriberUpsertResults", subObj.Upsert(sub));

              // upsert a row in the Master Data Extension
              var de = DataExtension.Init(request.MasterDEKey);

              var row = {};
              row.EmailAddress = request.EmailAddress;
              row.SubscriberKey = request.SubscriberKey;
              row.FirstName = request.FirstName;
              row.LastName = request.LastName;
              row.JobTitle = request.JobTitle;
            row.Industry = request.Industry;
            row.Company = request.Company;

              if (debug) {
                Write("<br><br>DE row: " + Stringify(row));
              }

              try {

                // attempt to add a row
                SetVar("rowAddResults", de.Rows.Add(row));

              } catch (e1) {

                 if (debug) {
                   Write("<br><br>Exception (1): " + e1);
                 }

                 try {

                    SetVar("rowUpdateResults", de.Rows.Update(row, ['SubscriberKey'], [request.SubscriberKey]));

                 } catch (e2) {

                    if (debug) {
                     Write("<br><br>Exception (2): " + e2 + " " + Stringify(request));
                    }

                 }
              }

              SetVar("overallResult", "success");

          } catch(e3) {

              SetVar("overallResult", "error");

          }

        } // EmailAddress check

    } // POST

    // sets JS and AMPScript variables
    function SetVar(varName, varValue){
        request[varName] = varValue;
        Variable.SetValue(varName, varValue);
    }

    if (debug) {
        Write("<br><br>" + Stringify(request) + "<br><br>");
    }

</script><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body style="pointer-events: all;">
      <div data-theme="default">
    <header class="header-1VDfFpd is-active-3bJUBFm" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1;">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-3cJG1eg">
                <div data-type="slot" data-key="headerlogo" data-label="Drop blocks or content here">
                    <div class="headerContainer"><a href="https://www.paramount.com/"><img
                            src="https://image.email.paramountusdistribution.com/lib/fe34117171640579731072/m/1/dc0f97bd-d0d0-4027-9f0f-4f54dbe52424.png"
                            alt="Paramount logo" class="headerLogo"></a></div>
            </div>

            <div class="logo-1Ik1c5s"><a href="https://www.viacbs.com/home" class=""><span data-icon="logo"
                                                                                           class="logo container-nVyjt3h icon">
                                                                                           
              
              <svg id="viacbs-logo" viewBox="0 0 200 25" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>


    <polygon id="path-1"
             points="0.08823 0.0859 22.92513 0.0859 22.92513 24.89986 0.08823 24.89986"></polygon>
    <polygon id="path-3" points="0.07391 0.0544 20.9 0.0544 20.9 24.7316 0.07391 24.7316"></polygon>
  </defs>

</svg>

              
              
              </span></a>
    </header>
      %%[ if @method == "GET" then ]%%

        <form id="form1" action="%%=v(@urlThis)=%%" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
         <fieldset style="margin-left: 15rem;font-size: 20;;">
          <input type="hidden" name="SubscriberKey" value="%%=v(@SubscriberKey)=%%">

          <label for="Email Address">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" name="EmailAddress" value="%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%">
<br> <br>
          
          <label for="First Name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="%%=v(@FirstName)=%%">
<br> <br>
          <label for="Last Name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="LastName" value="%%=v(@LastName)=%%">
<br> <br>
          <label for="JobTitle">Job Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="JobTitle" value="%%=v(@JobTitle)=%%">
<br> <br>           
                     <label for="Industry">Industry</label>
          <input type="text" name="Industry" value="%%=v(@Industry)=%%">
<br> <br>           
                     <label for="Company">Company</label>
          <input type="text" name="Company" value="%%=v(@Company)=%%">

         </fieldset>
                    <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"
                    class="button enable-transitions-3E-wyn2 button-2uhxaF8 icon-right-3vjNSZO link-2COyBkh" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 73rem;">
                <span class="background-33OWHL5" style=""></span>
                <span class="wrapper-3MsEabY">
                        <span class="label-IJilfVW" style="">Submit</span>
                    </span>
            </button>
        </form>


      %%[ elseif @method == "POST" then ]%%

        %%[ if @overallResult == "success" then ]%%

          <h1>Thanks</h1>
          We got your updates.

        %%[ elseif @overallResult == "error" then ]%%

          <h1>Oops!</h1>
          We had some trouble.

        %%[ endif ]%%


      %%[ endif ]%%
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is causing the error since I didn't change much from the boiler plate, and the cloud page id where it is hosted was overridden by salesforce to be a custom profile center as well.
I'm still learning so please be gentle :')

Edit:

Requested by the man itself:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screenshot of your ExampleMaster Data Extension fields?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I left it only with first name, last name, and email. Changed de "ExampleMaster" DE to the actual Master Data extension and I keep getting 500 error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start collecting `JobTitle`, `Industry` and `Company`, you'll need to add these fields to your `ExampleMaster` DE.

Even without those fields existing, your page still works. In fact, I copied it directly in to my instance and it worked just fine, even with fields missing from the incoming URL.

To test the send context you'll need to link to your CloudPage using the CloudPagesURL AMPscript function, e.g.:

```
<a href="%%=CloudPagesURL(5362)=%%">Custom Preference Center Boilerplate</a>
```

Where `5362` is your page ID.

The Page ID can be found here:

[image]

Comment: I did all of that, but I keep getting the same error, maybe is because im sending it as a test? I'll ask SF support and update you guys :(